# convertPoint:FromView: not always returning the correct value

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, mkmapview

I need to convert my annotation's coordinates from my map coordinates system to my map view coordinates system. For this i'm using the convertPoint:FromView: method.

It's working but sometimes it returns a wrong value.

This is my code

```
- (CGFloat)relativeParentXPosition {
  NSLog(@"Point Origin: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(self.parentAnnotationView.frame.origin));

  CGPoint parentOrigin = [self.mapView convertPoint:self.parentAnnotationView.frame.origin 
                                         fromView:self.parentAnnotationView.superview];

  NSLog(@"NEW PARENT Origin: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(parentOrigin));

  return parentOrigin.x + self.offsetFromParent.x;
}
```

And this is the output:

> - Working
>
> Point Origin: {9.92118e+06, 1.2004e+07}
>
> NEW PARENT Origin: {39, 218}
>
> - NOT Working - returning the wrong value
>
> Point Origin: {9.92138e+06, 1.20039e+07}
>
> NEW PARENT Origin: {9.92138e+06, 1.20037e+07}

Did anyone got this problem ? I don't understand why it's happening ? Is that a bug from Apple ?
Thanks

Comment: What is the relationship between self.mapView and self.parentAnnotationView.superview?

Comment: When you ask your question i asked myself why i'm using superview. And i though i'm using it because i'm using the wrong method. So i change my code to [self.mapView convertCoordinate:self.parentAnnotationView.annotation.coordinate toPointToView:self.mapView] and it works ! So thank you for putting me on the right track

Answer (score 0):

My bad, i was using the wrong method.
To get the coordinates of an annotation in the view coordinates we need to use the convertCoordinate: toPointToView: method.

```
CGPoint parentOrigin = [self.mapView convertCoordinate:self.parentAnnotationView.annotation.coordinate toPointToView:self.mapView];
```

Thanks @Jeffery Thomas for putting me on the right track